# Downloading Correct Dotnet Architecture

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos-big-sur

I have a Mac running M1 Big Sur. When I got on my project 6 months ago I downloaded Dotnet 5 and everything was fine. Last night I downloaded VS 2022 (use VS Code for work) to learn via a Udemy video and it upgraded me to dotnet 6.0.4.

Today when I went to run my dotnet locally on my Run and Debug, I got this error

[image: Initial Error]

I've been trying for hours to find a compatible run time for the project but nothing I found is working, closest I got was this article here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59168 which has a 14 step process further down.

I got dotnet 5 back on my machine, but now I get this error:
[image: New Error]

What do I need to do to get my architecture right to launch the project? To show my work, these are all the articles I have visited today, I promise I'm not being lazy, I just learned to code via a bootcamp 9 months ago and I am just now learning about these packages and how to use them, a lot of this is just going over my head. Any help would be appreciated.

My work:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52411

https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/qwus6a/net_5_sdk_not_installing_properly_on_m1_mac/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos?tabs=netcore2x#dependencies

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22380

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for resolving this was to manually remove dotnet from the usr/local/share folder. Then re-install dotnet 5.0 without dotnet 6.